# FourSquare venue search limit parameter capping out at 20?

Tags: foursquare

The foursquare [venue search api documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) states that the limit parameter can go up to 50, but if I set it to 50, I only get 20 results.  I know I'm using the api correctly because if I set the limit to 5, I get 5 results.  Is there something special I need to do to get 50 results?

For reference, here is the url I am using:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + latlong + '&client_id=myclientid&client_secret=myclientsecret&v=20120214&limit=50
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please post the latlong you are using?

Comment: I found I was doing something quite dumb in another part of my code.  False alarm!  Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that was cutting out all the venues past 20 in another part of my code before I got around to seeing the results.  So it was entirely user error.  Woops!